# Yesod: Connecting to an existing database with data

Tags: haskell, yesod

I have gone through this [chapter](http://www.yesodweb.com/book/persistent) and all the examples mentioned there are making the database schema initially and then operating over them.

But what to do if there is already an existing database schema with data ? Is there any way to create schema from it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `sql=` attributes in the models file to specify the table and column names in the existing schema. In this setup, you likely want to avoid using Persistent's automatic migration capabilities as well.

Comment: Ah, thanks. This is even mentioned in the web version of the book. I don't know how I missed in the hard copy of the book. :) Maybe you should also include this in the cookbook.

Comment: The cookbook is an open wiki, it would be great if you could submit an example of the kind of thing you're using this for.

Comment: Sure, will do it in a couple of days.